# How can I get Xamarin account?

Tags: xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin .. I found that there is an account called Xamarin account.
Visual Studio 2017 -> Tools Menu -> Xamarin Account.

However, I don't follow how can I get such Xamarin Account .. so do you have any suggestions about how to get or create Xamarin Account ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no Xamarin accounts anymore.

Xamarin used to be an independent company until Microsoft acquired it in 2016. When it was an independent company, you had to use your Xamarin account to pay for your Xamarin license.

Today, Xamarin is free and included in Visual Studio 2017.

Edit: The Xamarin Component Store has been deprecated and is now obsolete.

Comment: So, Why Visual Studio 2017 requires to add Xamarin Account into Tools -> Xamarin Account.
Also, To get more components in Xamarin iPhone projects in Visual Studio 2017 .. It is required to add your Xamarin Account

Comment: Are you referring to the Xamarin Component Store? The Xamarin Component Store has been deprecated and is now obsolete.